# Close a Simulink mask using M-Code

Tags: matlab, simulink, mask

I have been looking for a solution on the mathworks but found nothing. I need to control opening and closing of a simulink mask using code.

I can open the mask with:

```
open_system(gcb, 'mask')
```

But I cannot close it with:

```
close_system(gcb, 'mask')
```

Solution must work on matlab 2011b & 2014b

Any clue ? I need to support a block on both matlab 2011b and 2014b and the work flow and behavior are different, forcing me to control a mask close/open under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Found it,

```
close_system(gcb)
```

Is enough. Don't know why it didn't work the first time however.

Comment: I noticed that close_system(gcb) is equivalent to "cancel", how to save mask values first ?